# Relative postioning of dojox.widget.Toaster

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

**Context**

I am using `dojox/Widget/Toaster` in the page, but its position is at the extreme corners (br or tr). And on the extreme corners, there are headers and footers having the same colour as that of the background of `Toaster`.

**Question**

What I want is, to display the `Toaster` either slightly above the footer, or slightly below the header, so that the colours don't overlap. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself!
The solution is to change the CSS of `.dijitToasterClip` and specify the `top` and `left` attributes with the offset from top and left of the screen.